# JavaScript while loop error: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, while-loop

So I have made a code for some coursework, the code is suppose to start a function on page load which will then run the function of changing the traffic light image on screen. It is suppose to keep on changing forever however the program crashes or fails to load when I try to run. Before you suggest the problem is that the variable used in the condition isnt changed, I have tried to change it in the following code. when I ran it in the chrome debugger this is the thing that came up; 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <'.

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body onload="infinity()">
        <p></p>
        <h1>Traffic Light Sequence</h1>
        <img id ="trafficlight" src="r.jpg">
        <script>
            var images  = [
                "r.jpg",
                "randy.jpg",
                "g.jpg",
                "y.jpg"
            ];
            var counter = 0;
            function start() {
                counter = counter + 1;
                if(counter == images.length) counter=0;
                var image = document.getElementById("trafficlight");
                image.src=images[counter];
            }
            var a = 100;
            function infinity() {
                while (200>a) {
                    setTimeout(start(), 3000);
                }
                a = a - 25;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `a = a - 25;` should be inside the loop. Also, remove the parentheses on `start()` for the `setTimeout`

Comment: You didn't say what the error is. That's rather important.

Comment: Open your console, use the debugger, and tell us exactly what is wrong and why it confuses you.

Comment: I think I ran it in a debugger in google chrome, it said this when I ran it 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <'. Also I moved the a = a - 25; in the loop and I removed the brackets off the 'start' in the setTimeout.

Comment: What should I do now?  http://imgur.com/a/UkbKP

Comment: @ajt Where's the error? You need to make it easier to help you.

Comment: I dont know what is where the error is in the program, that is what I am asking. It doesnt start up in google chrome, so it is crashing or something on page load. Is there anything else you need from me so you can identify the problem?

Comment: @ajt The error will have a line and character number associated with it.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/4H7hO

Comment: that is the screenshot of me putting the code in the debugger. It says 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <' on the first line where it says DOCTYPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting while loop and setTimeout, use setInterval. The below code will work I think. It will change the image 100 times

```js
var url="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/thumbs/2017/";
var a=0,Handler;
var images  = ["yosemite_national_park_winter_4k-t1.jpg","namib_coastal_desert_4k-t1.jpg","beach_dock-t1.jpg"];
var counter = 0;
function start() {
  counter = counter + 1;
  a++;
  if(a>=100 && Handler)
    clearInterval(Handler);
  if(counter == images.length) counter=0;
  var image = document.getElementById("trafficlight");
  image.src=url+images[counter];
  return;
}
function infinity() { 
    Handler=setInterval(start, 3000); 
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body onload="infinity()">
        <p></p>
        <h1>Traffic Light Sequence</h1>
        <img id ="trafficlight" src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/thumbs/2017/yosemite_national_park_winter_4k-t1.jpg">
        <script>
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question already has an answer, but i just figured that the following code might be a better and a relatively simpler way of doing it.

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body onload="infinity()">
        <p></p>
        <h1>Traffic Light Sequence</h1>
        <img id ="trafficlight" src="r.jpg">
        <script>
            var images  = [
                "red.JPG",
                "green.jpg",
                "randy.jpg",
                "yellow.JPG"
            ];
            function infinity() {
              var counter = 0,
                  image = document.getElementById("trafficlight"),
                  a = 5,
                  timeoutInterval = 3000;
              setInterval(function() {
                counter++;
                if(counter == images.length) counter=0;
                if (a>=0) {
                    image.src=images[counter];
                    a--;
                }else{
                    // this else case is in the event that the timeout
                    // variable is 1, which is essentially 1ms, which 
                    // is bad as it would make your cpu usage go to a
                    // 100%
                    if (timeoutInterval <= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER - 2) {
                        // the above if condition is to stop timeoutInterval
                        // from ever reaching 2^53 which would cause an 
                        // overflow
                        timeoutInterval *= 2;
                        Math.pow(timeoutInterval, 20);
                    }
                }
              }, timeoutInterval);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

P.S. my laptop is still hot from running your infinite loop code of an example